# How to use namespaces in PHP

Tags: php, namespaces

I am trying to learn the basic concept of namespace and trying to implement but it always gives an error

The following is the method that I have used for namespaces

First I create a folder name `namespace` inside the folder name `www`, then I create two files

1. functions.php
2. index.php

I am writing the following code in `functions.php`

```
namespace MyProject;

function connect(){

echo 'connecting';

}
```

Code in `index.php`

```
echo \MyProject\connect();
```

Now I am running the file it always gives an error - by why? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `file it always gives an error` and we cant see that error unless you mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you mentioning **including** the functions file.

```
require('functions.php');
echo MyProject\connect();
```

Namespaces aren't substitutes for includes; the "magic" you see in frameworks or other structured code is likely an **autoloader** which takes care of converting namespaces to a folder/file structure and then including the file needed.